# Why does my Raspberry Pi SPI write loop pause for about 15ms? Context switch?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry Pi managing and writing to an FPGA. I use the SPI bus and some GPIO's to get the data over the link. The SPI write happens in bursts of variable length - from a few tens of bytes up to about 8kB.

The FPGA SPI receive code has a timeout which I initially set to around 12ms (which was a guesstimated value). This is almost always OK, but today I found out that very occasional timeouts on the FPGA seem to be caused by the fact that RPi will occasionally pause for about 15ms in the middle of sending a byte.

The RPi python driver code looks pretty much like this:

```
for b in byte_array:
    send_byte()
```

where send_byte() is a simple function that calls the SPI byte write function in the GPIO library, with some checking of a BUSY line and retrying.

Generally, bytes go out a few hundred microseconds apart, so this sudden pause is odd. I am thinking it is probably caused by some sort of context switch - but the Pi is not doing much else (and running the stock Linux distro).

None of this is a big problem, I can easily increase the timeout with no problems. But I am curious. What causes a chip running Linux at several GHz to suddenly stop doing the only thing it is being asked to do for about 15ms - which is an eternity in this context?

If it WAS a problem - what could I do about it?

Comment: If you need timing guarantees, use a real-time OS. Python may pause for GC, and modern Linux distros have a pile of periodic events that can cause jitter

Comment: yes, I'm aware, thanks. Just that 15ms seems inordinately long for a processor running at 1.2GHz. I don't believe that this is GC, and there should be nothing in the background to block for that long. I wondered if anyone knew what.